# PHP - Generate file with random name?

Tags: php, download

How can I create a script that generates a txt file from form data with a random name and allow it for download temporally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question implements alot of things. To create a random name textfile you could use sth like this:

```
 /**
 * @param $file string full path to temp file
 * @param $content string to be written to the file
 * @return bool
 */
function writeContentToFile($file, $content)
{
    //mode 'a' - open to write - pointer to end - if not exists ->try to create
    $handle = fopen($file, 'a');

    //check if creation was successful
    if (!$handle) {
        $error = "Cannot open file ($file)";
        return false;
    }

    if (is_writable($file)) {
        //try to write content
        if (!fwrite($handle, $content)) {
            $error = "Cannot write to file ($file)";
            return false;
        }
        //close the file
        fclose($handle);
        return true;
    } else {
        $error = "The file $filename is not writable";
        return false;
    }
}

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$yourPath="your/path/to/";
$file=$yourPath.generateRandomString().".txt";
$content="content";
writeContentToFile($file,$content);
```

To actually download you could use sth like this:

```
function initDownload($file)
{
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file);
        header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        //actually download
        readfile($file);

        //delete the file since you said temporaly
        unlink($file);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use php function [uniqid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to generate random name

```
$content = "some text here";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/". uniqid() .".txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the file using:

```
$fileName = tempnam( $yourPath );
```

Store the creation date somewhere (database, text file).

On every request to your script, check if the date has expired your time limit. If yes, delete the file using `unlink`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `tempnam` function will generate a file with a random name: https://www.php.net/tempnam.

Answer (score 0):

Make a php script called `download.php`

The download link/form action can be `FDSFASFA.txt` which is sent to `download.php?id=FDSFASFA` from `htaccess`

In download.php you output the content like

```
header('Content-type: application/txt');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FDSFASFA.txt"');
echo $content;
```

You store the `FDSFASFA` token in the database and delete it after a few minutes.